# Python- lazily read file which does not have new lines

Tags: python, file

So I'm aware that one can iterate on a file, which will read input until new line.

I have a file which does not contain new lines, but is too large to fit into memory. Is there a way to read a file word by word?

The only way I can think of is to read a limited number of bytes, find the last space, and yield the space separated words, while keeping the last not finished word in memory.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the data looks like?  Without a glance, can you use the csv library to read it with a different delimiter?

Comment: Looks like it's a duplicate, thanks @njzk2